# How can the 'fling/flick scrolling' be disabled in CefSharp.Wpf?

Tags: wpf, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Is there a way to disable the 'touch fling scrolling' behaviour in CefSharp.Wpf (or potentially via Cef, Chromium, etc)?

I appreciate it's an unusual request as touch fling scrolling is a great feature.  But unfortunately, I need to integrate with a dodgy touch screen hw/driver which works nicely for drag.. but fails miserably when flick scrolling as it consistently 'over scrolls'.  e.g. a gentle flick on the screen causes the page content to scroll multiple pages (instead of just a few lines).

Comment: What command line args have you tried exactly? For what it's worth the WPF implementation forwards touch events to the underlying CEF browser https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/92/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L2470

Comment: Initially, tried several chromium settings related to graphics rendering believeing that to the be issue, e.g. disable-gpu, disable-rtc-smoothness-algorithm, disable-low-res-tiling, etc.  Then after confirming it wasn't a CPU/graphic issue by replacing the touchscreen controller with something more modern (which has no flick scrolling issues) I tried various settings regarding scrolling, e.g. disable-threaded-scrolling, disable-smooth-scrolling, pull-to-refresh, disable-scroll-to-text-fragment, etc.

I've read through that part of the code which looks simple and solid.

Comment: One thing that I had tried with some limited success.. added a Thread.Sleep(100) (bad I know inside a routed event) when processing TouchAction.Up BEFORE brower.GetHost().SendTouchEvent() is invoked.  This stopped the flick scrolling.. but it's far too hacky.

Comment: How does the touch screen behave when using chrome? Same or better?

Comment: CefSharp.WebForm, Chrome, Chromium, and Edge (all using the same engine) all exhibit the EXACT same 'over scroll' problem.  The only difference is that CefSharp.Wpf requires 1 finger for the fling effect, whereas the others require 2 fingers for the fling effect (which is presumably due to the CefSharp.Wpf touch implementation you referenced earlier).

Comment: Does disabling flicks in WPF make any difference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.stylus.isflicksenabled?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Input_Stylus_IsFlicksEnabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236752/discussion-between-stoj-and-amaitland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no CefSharp/Cef/Chromium flag or public method available to cancel Chromium's fling behavior.

Fortunately though, Chromium does internally cancel the fling behavior under certain scenarios (refer Chromium's [fling_controller.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:content/browser/renderer_host/input/fling_controller.cc)).  One such scenario is a user touch down event.

So the trick is to simulate a touch down cancel event pair. Because CefSharp doesn't offer a 'post touch down' event for users to implement the logic (i.e. too much of an edge case), the easiest way is to implement the feature via a derived class.

Here's a complete example (with dependency property binding) in case it helps anyone else look for the same solution..

```
public class ChromiumWebBrowserEx : ChromiumWebBrowser
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlingDisabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsFlingDisabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ChromiumWebBrowserEx));

    public bool IsFlingDisabled
    {
        get => (bool) GetValue(IsFlingDisabledProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsFlingDisabledProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnTouchUp(TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTouchUp(e);

        if (IsFlingDisabled)
            CancelFling(e);
    }

    private void CancelFling(TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        // cancel the fling by creating a pseudo touch down followed by a cancellation
        var touchPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(this);
        if (touchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Up)
        {
            var touchEvent = new TouchEvent
                {
                    Id = e.TouchDevice.Id,
                    X = (float) touchPoint.Position.X,
                    Y = (float) touchPoint.Position.Y,
                    PointerType = PointerType.Touch,
                    Modifiers = WpfExtensions.GetModifierKeys(),
                    Type = TouchEventType.Pressed
                };

            GetBrowser().GetHost().SendTouchEvent(touchEvent);

            touchEvent.Type = TouchEventType.Cancelled;
            GetBrowser().GetHost().SendTouchEvent(touchEvent);
        }
    }
}
```